# Traducir una clase de java a c#

Tags: java, c#, .net, matrices

Estoy en un reto de *hackerrank* y tengo un inconveniente con la siguiente.
Por ejemplo no se que es `Scanner` y otras tantas partes del código, alguien me podría ayudar a corregirlo?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
    Solution solution = null;
    int testcases = ob.nextInt();
    ob.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < testcases; i++)
    {
        String numsLine = ob.nextLine();
        String[] numsLineParts = numsLine.trim().split(" ");
        int dimensions = Integer.valueOf(numsLineParts[0]);
        int numOperations = Integer.valueOf(numsLineParts[1]);
        solution = new Solution(dimensions);

        for (int j = 0; j < numOperations; j++)
        {
            String line = ob.nextLine();
            String[] lineParts = line.split(" ");

            if (lineParts[0].equals("UPDATE"))
            {
                solution.update(Integer.valueOf(lineParts[1]) - 1, Integer.valueOf(lineParts[2]) - 1, Integer.valueOf(lineParts[3]) - 1, Integer.valueOf(lineParts[4]));
            }

            if (lineParts[0].equals("QUERY"))
            {
                solution.query(Integer.valueOf(lineParts[1]) - 1, Integer.valueOf(lineParts[2]) - 1, Integer.valueOf(lineParts[3]) - 1, Integer.valueOf(lineParts[4]) - 1, Integer.valueOf(lineParts[5]) - 1, Integer.valueOf(lineParts[6]) - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Buenas noches alejandro, el reto me lo enviaron en un documento en word, en este momento no tengo el conocimiento en ese lenguaje pero si he aprendido bastante c#, por eso en este momento necesito pasarlo a ese lenguaje, ya que así se me facilita estudiarlo

Comment: Buenas Camilo, creo que te estás confundiendo, el fragmento de código que has puesto no es de C++, es de java. Te recomiendo mirar la documentación de la [API de java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) para que entiendas lo que hace cada cosa.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

En esta [dirección](https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/download.html) tienes herramientas conversoras:

```
using System;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
    Solution solution = null;
    int testcases = ob.Next();
    ob.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < testcases; i++)
    {
        string numsLine = ob.nextLine();
        string[] numsLineParts = numsLine.Trim().Split(" ", true);
        int dimensions = Convert.ToInt32(numsLineParts[0]);
        int numOperations = Convert.ToInt32(numsLineParts[1]);
        solution = new Solution(dimensions);

        for (int j = 0; j < numOperations; j++)
        {
            string line = ob.nextLine();
            string[] lineParts = line.Split(" ", true);

            if (lineParts[0].Equals("UPDATE"))
            {
                solution.update(Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[1]) - 1, Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[2]) - 1, Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[3]) - 1, Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[4]));
            }

            if (lineParts[0].Equals("QUERY"))
            {
                solution.query(Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[1]) - 1, Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[2]) - 1, Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[3]) - 1, Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[4]) - 1, Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[5]) - 1, Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[6]) - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Demasiado crack!! muchas gracias, ya me pongo a probar todo. un saludo muy grande

Comment: -1. No existe la clase Scanner en C#.